# Deep Copying an array using JQuery cannot copy array of Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following is my use case
I have objects `a` , `b` which has the following structure

```
 a={arr1:[obj1={x1:1,x2:2}, obj2={x1:4,x2:4}] , arr2:[obj1={x3:55,x4:66},obj2= 
     {x3:77,x4:88}]}


 b={arr1:[obj1={x1:1,x2:2}, obj2={x1:4,x2:4},obj3={x1:44,x2:46}] , arr2:[obj1= 
     {x3:55,x4:66},obj2={x3:77,x4:88},obj1={x3:34,x4:45}]}
```

I want to copy the contents of `a` to `b`

I tried using  `b=$.extend(true,b,a)`

but the contents of `a` are not copied in `b`. Object `b` remains unchanged. The JSON format output of `b` is as follows.

```
{"arr1":[{"x1":1,"x2":2},{"x1":4,"x2":4},{"x1":44,"x2":46}],"arr2":[{"x3":55,"x4":66},{"x3":77,"x4":88},{"x3":34,"x4":45}]}
```

So what is the way to copy array contents.

Comment: What is your expected outcome array looks like ?

Comment: Hmm, b contains all values from a so what do you want to extend in b?

Comment: `$.extend` doesn't suit for a such task. You have two arrays of some objects, which has some custom identifier field. So if you want to merge your arrays, you should iterate all its items and populate result array manually. It can be done a littler bit easier with a library like `underscore`, but it is not necessary at all.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can join a Object Array into another.

I think this is pretty straight forward. Questions? Ask me in the comments :)

```js
array1 = [{x:10, y:15}, {x:17, y:15}, {x:17, y:13}];
array2 = [{x:20, y:29}, {x:21, y:25}, {x:27, y:22}];
for(i=0; array1.length>i; i++){
  array2.push(array1[i]);
}
console.log(array2);
```